Filter to select pairs of rows
I am trying to filter pairs (identified by id) based on conditions. I have the following data frame,
id <- c(1,1,2,2,1,1,3,3,4,4)

PorF <- c("start","fail","start","pass","start","pass","start","pass","start","fail")

timest <- c(as.POSIXct("2021-05-08 08:15:07"),
            as.POSIXct("2021-05-08 08:15:45"),
            as.POSIXct("2021-05-28 08:17:09"),
            as.POSIXct("2021-05-28 08:17:25"),
            as.POSIXct("2021-05-28 08:32:07"),
            as.POSIXct("2021-05-28 08:32:12"),
            as.POSIXct("2021-05-28 08:33:14"),
            as.POSIXct("2021-05-28 08:33:45"),
            as.POSIXct("2021-05-28 08:34:12"),
            as.POSIXct("2021-05-28 08:34:56"))


testdf <- data.frame(id, PorF, timest)
testdf

> testdf
   id  PorF              timest
1   1 start 2021-05-08 08:15:07
2   1  fail 2021-05-08 08:15:45
3   2 start 2021-05-28 08:17:09
4   2  pass 2021-05-28 08:17:25
5   1 start 2021-05-28 08:32:07
6   1  pass 2021-05-28 08:32:12
7   3 start 2021-05-28 08:33:14
8   3  pass 2021-05-28 08:33:45
9   4 start 2021-05-28 08:34:12
10  4  fail 2021-05-28 08:34:56

I want to filter those IDs that has a start and a pass. All the pairs with start and fail should be filtered out.
My expected output should look like this,
> filtered_testdf
id  PorF              timest
2 start 2021-05-28 08:17:09
2  pass 2021-05-28 08:17:25
1 start 2021-05-28 08:32:07
1  pass 2021-05-28 08:32:12
3 start 2021-05-28 08:33:14
3  pass 2021-05-28 08:33:45

What I am trying is this which is not giving what I want,
testdf |> 
  group_by(id) |> 
  filter(PorF == "start" & PorF == "pass")

Any idea how to achieve the expected result?

You have several pairs with the same id, e.g. id 1 has a pair with start/pass AND start/fail. How do you identify a consecutive group?

After arrange(id) you will see consecutive pair with same id. I want the pair with has start-pass sequence.

arrange won't help. On the contrary, it will make the problem worse, because then you have 4 rows with id = 1 and programmatically it is not possible to distinguish the two pairs of rows from each other with the information you provided (unless you take into account, e.g. the timestamp). If the timestampe separates the pairs, please provide that information in your question.

You can do:
library(tidyverse)

testdf |> 
  mutate(id_helper = cumsum(PorF == "start")) |> 
  filter(any(PorF == "start") & any(PorF == "pass"), .by = id_helper)

Or equivalently:
testdf |> 
  mutate(id_helper = cumsum(PorF == "start")) |> 
  filter(!any(PorF == "fail"), .by = id_helper)

  id  PorF              timest id_helper
1  2 start 2021-05-28 08:17:09         2
2  2  pass 2021-05-28 08:17:25         2
3  1 start 2021-05-28 08:32:07         3
4  1  pass 2021-05-28 08:32:12         3
5  3 start 2021-05-28 08:33:14         4
6  3  pass 2021-05-28 08:33:45         4

Note that I had to create an additional id variable since (see my comment above) there are several pairs of rows with the same id (i.e. id 1 has two pairs).

you could use id_helper = consecutive_id(id) as well

Oh wow! I didn't know that function. This seems like a very good helper, indeed.

You could write a little helper function that splits the data into two based on the first (start) or second (result) row of each "pair" (assuming your pairs are contiguous) and then finds the rows in the second one that passed (or failed). Then combine them.
filter_pair <- function(data, result) {
  df <- split(data, 1:2)
  idx <- which(df[[2]][,'PorF']==result)
  rbind(df[[1]][idx,], df[[2]][idx,]) |>
    dplyr::arrange(id, timest)
}

filter_pair(testdf, "pass")

  id  PorF              timest
1  1 start 2021-05-28 08:32:07
2  1  pass 2021-05-28 08:32:12
3  2 start 2021-05-28 08:17:09
4  2  pass 2021-05-28 08:17:25
5  3 start 2021-05-28 08:33:14
6  3  pass 2021-05-28 08:33:45


filter_pair(testdf, "fail")

  id  PorF              timest
1  1 start 2021-05-08 08:15:07
2  1  fail 2021-05-08 08:15:45
3  4 start 2021-05-28 08:34:12
4  4  fail 2021-05-28 08:34:56


Instead of  dplyr::arrange(id, timest) we might do sort_by(~id+timest)?

A base R option but follows the same philosophy of deschen's solution
> subset(testdf, !ave(PorF == "fail", cumsum(PorF == "start")))
  id  PorF              timest
3  2 start 2021-05-28 08:17:09
4  2  pass 2021-05-28 08:17:25
5  1 start 2021-05-28 08:32:07
6  1  pass 2021-05-28 08:32:12
7  3 start 2021-05-28 08:33:14
8  3  pass 2021-05-28 08:33:45

